# oVirt: access external Provider through Proxy

Tags: ovirt

Today I updated my ovirt-engine to 2.4 and noticed the external Provider "ovirt-node-repository" (Openstack/Glance) that is now configured by default.

The URL of this external provider is http://glance.ovirt.org:9292, but unfortunatle my ovirt-node machine sits in a private network where it can only access external services through a HTTP proxy.

Is there a way to tell ovirt-engine the HTTP-Proxy to use ?